# Scrapy insert into mongodb doesn't work

Tags: python, mongodb, scrapy, database

I have problem when i tried to save my scrape result into mongodb. On terminal not show error, but data did not save into mongodb.

pipline.py

```
class MongoDBPipeline(object):

    collection_name = 'lalaland'

    def __init__(self, mongo_uri, mongo_db):
        self.mongo_uri = mongo_uri
        self.mongo_db = mongo_db

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(
            mongo_uri = crawler.settings.get('MONGO_URI'),
            mongo_db = crawler.settings.get('MONGO_DATABASE', 'items')
        )

    def open_spider(self, spider):
        self.client = MongoClient(self.mongo_uri)
        self.db = self.client[self.mongo_db]

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.client.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.db[self.collection_name].insert(dict(item))
        logging.debug("Added to mongo")
        return item
```

settings.py

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'lalaland.pipelines.MongoDBPipeline':300
}

MONGO_URI = 'mongodb://localhost:27017'
MONGODB_DATABASE = 'lala_db'
```

item.py

```
class InforItem(Item):
    link = Field()
    caption = Field()
```

spider.py

```
item = InfoItem()
        item['link'] = response.url
        item['body'] = ' '.join(response.xpath("//li[@class='_cak6a'][1]/h1/span//text()").extract())
yield item
```

Comment: Where are you calling `process_item`? In another words, where is the remaining code?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand what do you mean, process_item inside pipline.py for receive data.

Comment: Where do you call the instance method `process_item` in `MongoDBPipeline`?

Comment: if i not wrong, the method should be call in method parse.

Comment: And where is "parse"?

Comment: Are items printed in your console while scrapy crawls?